# How to center an image within a div (both vertical and horizontal) and cut off excess?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible in CSS to achieve the following:

[image]

With the following being the html and css:

```
<div class="preview">
  <img src="/big-ass-image.png" width="150" height="500" border="0"/>
</div>

.preview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

So that only the part of the image in the div (gray box in the mockup above) is showing, and the middle part of the image is shown with the rest cut off.

Comment: Why not use `margin`? I don't really see what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: What do you mean by using `margin` for this? Basically I have large images but only want to show 200x100 of the image's center (and cut off the rest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this helps you with your query. If you have any questions, drop a comment and I'll try to amend my post to suit your needs.

```css
.preview {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.preview:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}

.preview img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use `position: absolute` on image and center it with `transform: translate` and set `overflow: hidden` on parent.

```css
.preview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.preview:hover {
  overflow: visible
}
```

```html
<div class="preview">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```